# Annotation chart with style="display:none" resize automaticly

Tags: charts, google-visualization

If I put the div where I draw the graph the "style = display: none" attribute, this resizes my chart in half.

```
<div id='chart_div_inmediata' style='width: 900px; height: 300px;display:none'></div>
```

Result :

```
<div id="chart_div_inmediata" class="google-visualization-atl container" style="width: 900px; height: 300px; display: none;">
<div class="" style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 200px;">
</div>
```

How do I fix this? Thank!